# Hiding specific reports/folders from showing in SSRS report server search results

Tags: reporting-services

My client has over 500 reports. They would like to archive half of them but keep them near in case they would like to reinstate them.

I created an "Archive" folder and moved reports there but now I would like to hide these reports from appearing in search results. Is there a way to control search results in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your scenario is Report Manager.

No there is no way to control the search results in Report Manager.  It is a very cheap and cheerful portal.

Instead I would load the reports into a Visual Studio project or projects (if they aren't already).  That way the source code can be preserved off-line and they can be redeployed in the future.